# $X\to X/G$ is a finite morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, automorphism-group, integral-extensions

Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of automorphisms acting on an affine variety $X\subset\mathbb{A}^n$.

I'm trying to prove that the natural projection $\pi:X\to X/G$ is a finite map.

First, I'm a bit confused about the quotient $X/G$. If I've understood it correctly, according to Shafarevich's *Basic Algebraic Geometry I*, section I.$2.3$, example $11$, the quotient can be seen $X/G$ as an affine variety (since $A(X)^G$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra). But take $X=Z(x^2+y^2-1)\subset\mathbb{A}^2$ and $G=\{id, \alpha\}$, where $\alpha$ is the antipodal map. Don't we get $X/G\simeq\mathbb{P}^1$, which is not affine?

Besides, how do I prove that $\pi^*:A(X)^G\hookrightarrow A(X)$ is integral? I can see it for specific examples (like the one above), but not in general. Any hints?

Comment: $\overline{k}(X)^G$ is the function field of $X/G$ and $\overline{k}(X)/\overline{k}(X)^G$ is a degree $|G|$ Galois extension. Picking some transcendental elements $t_1,\ldots,t_d \in \overline{k}(X)^G$ then $\overline{k}(X)^G \cong \text{Frac}(\overline{k}[t_1,\ldots,t_d,Y_1,\ldots,Y_j]/I)$  the function field of the affine variety $V(I)$, but I don't see how to ensure a map $\pi : X \to V(I)$. Also if some $f_i$ generate $\overline{k}(G)$ then the elementary symmetric polynomials in $( f_i^\sigma)_{\sigma \in G}$ generate $\overline{k}(X/G)$

Comment: @reuns, I know there is a way to find $\pi$ given that $I$ is prime (i.e., $V(I)$ is irreducible), but we can't guarantee that, right? Is that why you say you don't see how to ensure $\pi$?

Comment: In what I wrote $\overline{k}(X)^G$ is a finite extension of $F = \overline{k}(t_1,\ldots,t_d)$ thus $\overline{k}(X)^G = F[Y_1,\ldots,Y_j]/J$ where $J$ is a prime and maximal ideal of $F$ and you can try things like $I = J \cap \overline{k} [t_1,\ldots,t_d,Y_1,\ldots,Y_j]$, a prime ideal of $\overline{k}[t_1,\ldots,t_d,Y_1,\ldots,Y_j]$. But the $t_i,Y_j$ are rational variables in those you used to define $X$, that's why the map $\pi$ isn't obvious (probably it works better when enlarging to projective varieties)

Comment: @reuns, in the example $11$ fromShafarevich, he says that $A(X)^G$ can be proven to be a finitely generated algebra (appendix $4$ in the book), so that $A(X)^G\simeq k[y_1,...,y_k]/I$ for some ideal $I$. If $I$ is prime, this corresponds to an affine (irreducible) variety $Y$ with $I(Y)\simeq A(X)^G$. In this case, $\pi$ should be guaranteed, right?

Comment: And that's what's bugging me: if $Y$ is affine, how can $X/G\simeq \mathbb{P}^1$ in the example I mentioned? I can't see what I'm missing

Comment: In your example $X/G$ is not $\mathbb{P}^1$ at all!  We're working over an algebraically closed field, not over $\mathbb{R}$.